# cannot change the tui window size when using gdb in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, gdb, tui

I am using the -tui in gdb on ubuntu 14.04, the window of the tui often become very small automatically, to be strict, it often suddenly turn to smaller when I began to type, but each time the key is not the same, the same thing seems to be that I had stared at the screen for several minutes (a little long) before I type any key. I don't know why. When I try to use

winheight src +4

or

winheight SRC +4

it didn't change at all, and it keeps give me the usage information. I have no idea how to fix this problem, could anybody give me some clue?
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKvH0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following to set up gdb with tui and 3 windows (i.e,, registers, disassembly, and command)?

```
$ gdb -q -tui <file>
```

Then when in gdb:

```
(gdb) break main
(gdb) run
(gdb) layout asm
(gdb) layout reg
(gdb) list 10
```

The "list 10" command will list 10 lines of your source code in the middle window.  However, if don't need to see the registers then don't use the layout commands.

Comment: I use it like this: "sudo gdb -tui" then "attach 3456". I closed all the terminal and redo all these things again. Because I am debugging a multiple thread program, I didn't use the <file> option. By the way, what is the "-q" mean?

Comment: Yep... (-q) is just a habit I have ( --quiet Do not print version number on startup.); so it's not necessary. I use the -pid option but "attach" is good. I think you have to sudo to "attach" or -pid to a running process. My code is mainly Assembly so my examples may not suite your needs.